# Problem with a polynomial and its second derivative

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I need to prove the following:

**let p(x) be a polynomial with even degree and leading coefficient > 0, and p(x) - p''(x)>0 for all real x.**

**then p(x)>0 for all real x.**

Even a partial help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such polynomial needs to have a global minimum.

Suppose there exists $y$ such that $p(y)\leq 0$, and call $x$ the minimum, because it's a global minimum, we must have  $p''(x)\geq 0$ (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html) for example) and $p(x)\leq 0$ (this is because $p(x)\leq p(y)$ ). This means that $p(x)-p''(x)\leq 0$, which is a contradiction.